# Dependency inversion in EJB based application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb

I want to make some of parts my JEE application independent from others ones using dependency inversion and dependency injection. Below is some code of main core part, that uses **MyService**, but is independent from other module that should provide implementation of **MyService**.

```
public interface MyService {
    public void send(MyObject myObject);
}
```

.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyServiceWrapper implements MyService {

    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void send(MyObject myObject) {
        myService.send(myObject);
    }
}
```

To clarify:

**Module A contains classes**:

- MyObject,
- MyService,
- MyServiceWrapper,

**Module B contains implementation of MyService**.

I want **MyServiceWrapper** to have injected implementation of **MyService** provided by **module B**, so **module A** can call implementation of **MyService** by using **MyServiceWrapper**, but in te same time **module A** is independent from **module B**.

The problem with above code, is that container do not know which implementation of **MyService** should be injected.

How it should be written so **MyServiceWrapper**, so it won't be injected to itself, but proper implementation (provided in other module) will be injected instead?

Comment: May i ask why are you injecting an object to it self ? Are there any other implementations of MyService besides MyServiceWrapper ?

Comment: I have edited question to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Owkay, i think i might know. I have edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to use what is known as a `Qualifier` , one example from CDI would be the annotation `@Named`, this would get rid of ambiguity for the container.

```
public interface MyService {
void send(MyObject myObject);
}
```

and the implementation of `MyService` :

```
@Named("fromModuleA")
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyServiceWrapper implements MyService {

    @Inject
    @Named("fromModuleB")
    private MyService someOtherBean;

    @Override
    public void send(MyObject myObject) {
        this.someOtherBean.send(myObject);
    }
} 

@Named("fromModuleB")
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeOtherBeanFromModuleB implements MyService{
  @Override
    public void send(MyObject myObject) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

The `@Inject` comes from a Java specification called [CDI](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=365) (Context and Dependency Injection), with this annotation it doesn't matter whether you use it on EJBs or CDI beans, but @EJB will only work with the EJB Container. Also note you don't really need the Interface `MyService` at least not anymore but it's a good practice to code to the interface.